# How to convert a IResource into an object

Tags: eclipse-plugin

My aim is to display all the files(of a project) whose methods are annotated with an annotation in a view.

I successfully got all the file name of my project but I can't get to convert my resource into an object in order to test if it is annotated.

I have a `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7061636B` pointing to line   `ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);` which I can't explain myself. FYI, I have tried with FileInputStream but got the same result.

here is my code :

```java
    private boolean filenameIsAnnotated(IResource member) {
    // transform a IResource into an Object
    InputStream is = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Object object = null;
    try {
        is = ((IFile) member).getContents();
        File f = member.getLocation().toFile();
        is = new FileInputStream(f);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        object = ois.readObject();
        if (is != null && ois != null) {
            // verify that one of the method is annotated
            for (Method m : object.getClass().getMethods()) {
                System.out.println(" method  " + m.getName());
                if (m.isAnnotationPresent(SPECIFICANNOTATION))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (is != null && ois != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here are the method using this one, just in case :

```java
    /**
 * Recursively, go thru all the hierarchy of folders to find one given folder
 * and return all of its files. A Container can be a IFolder, IProject or
 * IWorkspaceRoot
 */
private ArrayList<String> processContainer(IContainer container, String filesLocationFolder) {
    IResource[] members = null;
    try {
        members = container.members();
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (IResource member : members) {
        if (member instanceof IContainer) {
            processContainer((IContainer) member, filesLocationFolder);
        } else if (member instanceof IFile) {
            if (container instanceof IFolder) {
                if (member.getFileExtension().equals("java")) {
                    //test if the file is annotated 
                    if (filenameIsAnnotated(member))
                        fileList.add(member.getLocation().toFile().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

and the method calling the precedent :

```java
private ArrayList<String> getFileList(String projectName, String filesLocationFolder) {
    // gets the workspace root
    IWorkspaceRoot currentRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = currentRoot.getProject(projectName);
    try {
        currentRoot.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
        project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        // Find the annotated files, return a list
    ArrayList<String> list = processContainer(project, filesLocationFolder);
    return list;
}
```

thank you for your help,
K

Comment: `IFile#getContents()` is already opening a file handle and an input stream to its contents. You don't need to convert it to a `java.io.File` and open it a second time. Also, if these are Java source files, why would you expect an `ObjectInputStream` to be  a valid way of reading them?

Comment: Files with extension java are just plain text files, you can't use `ObjectInputStream` on plain text. If you want to parse the Java code you need to use the JDT Java Model or AST as described [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html?utm_source=tuicool)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. I'm a beguinner, that's why I guess ;) I will read your link. If I understand well, i should do Ifile.getContent then use JDT to parse my java file. Could you please tell me when to use an ObjectInputStream for my general knowledge ? thanks

Comment: ObjectInputStream is only used to read a file that was written using ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: thank you for your help